# Why doesn't adding observer for a notification with blocks work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, nsnotificationcenter

I have this method to get shift my text fields when they keyboard appears:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {

    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0f, keyboardShift);
}
```

Then I tried to use the block method instead:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0f, keyboardShift);
}];
```

However, using this method I set a breakpoint inside the block but it's not being called. Is there anything I'm missing? Why doesn't this method work but the other one does?

Answer (score 0):

What if you try replacing the nil parameter for the queue with [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]

Also, if you go with the block API, make sure you keep a reference to the token returned so that you can remove the observer at the right time later on.

Comment: Changing that to `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` doesn't make a difference actually. How do I keep reference to the token?

Answer (score 0):

`addObserverForName` returns an object that you should hold on to. From the header:

> The return value is retained by the system, and should be held onto by the caller in order to remove the observer with removeObserver: later, to stop observation.

See the example in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:).